# Grabbing value of input after keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the value of an `input` field using `keyup`, and then grab it's value when clicking on a separate `button` element afterward. But code is not showing updated input value when I click on the button. What is the issue here?

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

    var text_input = $('.promo-bottom .gform_wrapper form .gform_body #input_8_2');

    text_input.on('keyup', function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr('value', value);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.promo-bottom .gform_wrapper form .gform_body a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var new_value = $('.promo-bottom .gform_wrapper form .gform_body #input_8_2').val();

        if (new_value != '') {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
            $('.promo-bottom .gform_wrapper form .gform_footer #gform_submit_button_8, .promo-reveal').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: quick question, since you are using an `id` why do you need all this `.promo-bottom .gform_wrapper form .gform_body #input_8_2` as selector? just `#input_8_2` will be enough right?  `var value = $(this).val();`  here do you have the right value?

Comment: @LakshanS, yes I can alert the value on keyup, but after I try to grab value on the button click, the value is `""` (empty).

Comment: what are you tring to do here ` $(this).attr('value', value);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic input fetching logic:

```js
var input = $('#myInput');

$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  console.log(input.val());
});

$('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput">
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

1. You don't need to set the value of the input on keyup
2. Try mapping the 'onClick' event on your button instead of the entire document
3. Comparisons should be '!==' instead of '!='